# html form method not calling script

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can anyone shed some light on this issue I am having regarding html form element. Basically I am developing a Wordpress site and on one of the pages I've got a form that when submitted I want to call a custom php script.

This is my code:

```
<form action="test.php">
    <div id="summary">
    <table id="ordertable">
        <tr><th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>   
    <input type="button" value="Confirm Order" class="confirmBtn"/>
    </form>
```

At the moment `test.php` should echo "TEST SCRIPT" but the `script` is never called and I don't know why...

Comment: is `test.php` in your root folder of WordPress or in your Theme folder?

Comment: Is it just loading a blank page then? does test.php exist? are there conditions in the text.php file?

Comment: never called? you get a white screen or a 404?

Comment: Type button doesn't submit form's you should use type="submit"

Answer (score 6):

`type="button"` inputs are for binding JavaScript to and nothing else.

Use `type="submit"` for a button that will submit the form.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin that was my issue, will accept answer in next few mins when able

Answer (score 0):

Your input type should be:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Confirm Order" class "confirmBtn"/>
```

Also specify a method in your form tag:

```
<form method = "post" action = "test.php">
```

Comment: The `method` attribute is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the method attr to your form in order to get your script working. It informs your server about the nature of data-flow. And change your input type to submit.

```
<form action="" method="GET/POST"></form>

<input type="submit"/>
```